# Get all values from intermediate table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL three-table many-to-many setup with link table, simplified here:

```
categories
  category_id
  category_name

categories2entries
  category_id,
  entry_id

entries
  entry_id
  entry_text
```

I need to return all entries for a given category name but I want to include a list of all the categories a given entry is attached to. For example, if a search is for `Addictions` and the entry is also listed in categories `Mental health` and `Young people`, I want an output field for each result with all three categories listed.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need direct lookup for to get the list of entries, and backward lookup for to get categories list for each entry. Backward lookup must use another tables copies.

```sql
SELECT e.entry_text,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c2.category_name) belongs_to
FROM categories c1
JOIN categories2entries ce1 ON c1.category_id = ce1.category_id
JOIN entries e ON ce1.entry_id = e.entry_id
JOIN categories2entries ce2 ON ce2.entry_id = e.entry_id
JOIN categories c2 ON c2.category_id = ce2.category_id
WHERE c1.category_name = 'Category Name'
GROUP BY e.entry_text
```

If you need the same for more than one category (maybe even all) then

```sql
SELECT c1.category_name,
       e.entry_text,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c2.category_name) belongs_to
FROM categories c1
JOIN categories2entries ce1 ON c1.category_id = ce1.category_id
JOIN entries e ON ce1.entry_id = e.entry_id
JOIN categories2entries ce2 ON ce2.entry_id = e.entry_id
JOIN categories c2 ON c2.category_id = ce2.category_id
  /* WHERE c1.category_name IN ({Category Names list}) */
GROUP BY c1.category_name,
         e.entry_text
```